# Add elements of a list at repeated (cyclic) indices to another list

Tags: python, list

Given these lists

```
source = [1,2,3]
additions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...]
```

Additions[] could be 2 items or 1000 items, source[] is always 3.
How can I iterate over additions[] and for every item, map and always add the additions value to the source value. So in the iteration:

```
source[1] + additions[1]
source[2] + additions[2]
source[3] + additions[3]
source[1] + additions[4] #reset source[] here
source[2] + additions[5]
...
```

So given the example, source[] would end up as:

```
source = [13,17,12]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you can *cycle* over indices using `itertools.cycle`.

```
from itertools import cycle

source = [1,2,3]
additions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for i, j in zip(cycle(range(len(source))), additions):
     source[i] += j

print(source)
[13, 17, 12]
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you Coldspeed